# How to target a specific parent div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's take this HTML for example:

```
<ul class="wrap">
 <li class="out"></li>
 <li class="out"></li>
 <li class="out">
     <ul class="wrap">
        <li class="out"></li>
        <li class="out"></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, what's the best way of targeting the list item that had a class of "wrap" but is not a child of the nested ul? Alternatively, how can I taget the li with a class of "wrap" that is nested in a ul which is nested in an li?

Answer (score 4):

For the un-nested li, you have two options:

```
$('ul.wrap:has(ul) > li') // For uls that specifically have a nested ul inside
$('ul.wrap > li:not(ul ul > li)') // For any top-level ul
```

For the nested li:

```
$('ul.wrap ul.wrap > li')
```

Answer (score 1):

ul which is nested with li:

```
$("li > ul.wrap > li")
```

ul which is not nested with li:

```
$("ul.wrap li:not(li > ul >li)")
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this, I believe:

```
$("ul.wrap li ul.wrap")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an "outer" ul and an "inner" ul. Selecting the inner ul is very easy, you just use a descendent-selector `ul.wrap ul.wrap`. In outer one is a little bit tricky, because you'll need to use a condition with a not selector: `ul.wrap:not(ul.wrap ul.wrap)`. You're basically saying: give me all the ul.wrap that do do not have a parent that have a wrap. If you want to select the "li's" use the direct selector i.e. `> li` behind each selector.

I've added it to an example for you to show it works:

Html:

```
<ul class="wrap" tag="outer">
 <li class="out"></li>
 <li class="out"></li>
 <li class="out">
     <ul class="wrap" tag="inner">
        <li class="out"></li>
        <li class="out"></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
alert($('ul.wrap:not(ul.wrap ul.wrap)').attr('tag'));
alert($('ul.wrap ul.wrap').attr('tag'));

alert($('ul.wrap:not(ul.wrap ul.wrap) > li').length);
alert($('ul.wrap ul.wrap > li').length);
```

**Ps. I wouldn't use 'li' selector to find the outer or inner ul.** You might encounter empty ul's if you fill them programatically (which will break a selector with that's dependent on li) and why should you use something you don't need?

Comment: It migth be useful to read a little bit about selectors on this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Have fun!